# Install node.js in ZSH shell

Tags: node.js, zsh

I installed node.js v9.7.1 in Windows 10. The files are located in Program Files. The Node.js command prompt states it is installed.

I then installed the Hyper terminal and installed Bash and then ZSH. In ZSH, `node -v` command is not found. Do I need to install a separate copy of nodejs in ZSH?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not found"? Can you share the full and exact error message, along with your debugging attempts?

Answer (score 2):

The bash for windows "Linux subsystem" Runs things slightly differently than your windows machine will and works off a slightly modified virtual file system. As this is the case you will need to install in via you bash / zsh terminal.

I recommend using NVM https://github.com/creationix/nvm.
nvm is just for installing and managing the versions of node on your machine.

Basic usage of NVM as Follows:

- `nvm list` will list all the versions of node you have installed
- `nvm install v*.*.*` will install a version
- `nvm use v *.*.*` will use an installed version

you use the node command `node -v` to see the version in use at that time.

More details on NVM commands here :
https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage

:)

Comment: Nathan, it worked like a charm, thanks. One thing, the '-v nvm' command does not work for me in bash || zsh. I just typed 'nvm' to verify the install.

Comment: `nvm list` will list all the versions of node you have installed
`nvm install v*.*.*` will install a version
`nvm use v *.*.*` will use an installed version
you use the node command `node -v` to see the version in use at that moment. nvm is just for installing and managing the versions of node on your machine.

more details on NVM commands here :
https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage

And:

https://gist.github.com/chranderson/b0a02781c232f170db634b40c97ff455

Also, please upvote the answer if you found it useful. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. I found this article and tried the solution out and it worked for me.
You have to add the nvm plugin in the ~/.zshrc file. Follow the steps in the article below.

https://www.makeschool.com/academy/track/standalone/environment-setup-39i/node-install-instructions

Hope this works for you too. :)

Comment: This link may answer the question but it is better to include the related parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes/Deleted.

Comment: As Akhilesh said, the link is not working now